# double/float conversion in C

Tags: c, double

I have this code

```
#define Third (1.0/3.0)
#define ThirdFloat (1.0f/3.0f)
int main()
{
    double a=1/3;
    double b=1.0/3.0;
    double c=1.0f/3.0f;
    printf("a = %20.15lf, b = %20.15lf, c = %20.15lf\n", a,b,c);
    float d=1/3;
    float e=1.0/3.0;
    float f=1.0f/3.0f;
    printf("d = %20.15f, e = %20.15f, f = %20.15f\n", d,e,f);

    double g=Third*3.0;
    double h=ThirdFloat*3.0;
    float i=ThirdFloat*3.0f;
    printf("(1/3)*3: g = %20.15lf; h = %20.15lf, i = %20.15f\n", g, h, i);
}
```

Which gives that output

```
a =    0.000000000000000, b =    0.333333333333333, c =    0.333333343267441
d =    0.000000000000000, e =    0.333333343267441, f =    0.333333343267441
(1/3)*3: g =    1.000000000000000; h =    1.000000029802322, i =    1.000000000000000
```

I assume that output for `a` and `d` looks like this because compiler casts integer value to float after division.
`b` looks good, `e` is wrong because of low `float` precision, so as `c` and `f`.

But i have no idea why `g` has correct value (i thought that `1.0/3.0 = 1.0lf/3.0lf`, but then `i` should be wrong) and why `h` isn't the same as `i`.

Comment: For `g`... didn't you notice that it's multiplied my three?

Comment: so basically you're asking why `(1.0 / 3.0) * 3.0` is 1?? and why is `(1.0f / 3.0f) * 3.0` not outputting 1?

Comment: Re `h` versus `i`: Because `3.0` is a double and `3.0f` is a float

Comment: Compilers tend to be very good at something called [*constant folding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), where compile-time constant expressions are evaluated at compile-time. Also, good compilers are also getting rather good to detect cases like shown for `g`, `h` and `i`, where a division by 3.0 followed by a multiplication by `3.0` cancel each other out.

Comment: Regarding the constant folding and calculation, even without optimizations enabled GCC 10.2 will convert all your calculation into constant values, as seen in the assembly [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rexhYW) (look at the constants in the end).

Comment: I noticed that g is multipiled, but why is this 1, no 0.999999? Computer should approximate 1.0/3.0 to 0.999999 and because od that g should be 2.9999997.
Corrent me if i'm mistaken. If we talk about float like 1.0f/3.0f i should think that computer sees 0.999999, but for double like 1.0/3.0 it isn't approximated, but it keeps exact value?

Comment: _"the decimal number 9.2 can be expressed exactly as a ratio of two decimal integers (92/10), both of which can be expressed exactly in binary (0b1011100/0b1010). However, the same ratio stored as a floating point number is never exactly equal to 9.2:"_ [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Use `"%.17e"` and `"%a"` for greater insight.

Comment: Okay but why then ThirdFloat*3.0 gives something strange, but ThirdFloat*3.0f is okey? I mean why float * double is less accurate than float * float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first look closer: use `"%.17e"` (approximate decimal) and `"%a"` (exact).

```
#define Third (1.0/3.0)
#define ThirdFloat (1.0f/3.0f)
#define FMT "%.17e, %a"
int main(void) {
    double a=1/3;
    double b=1.0/3.0;
    double c=1.0f/3.0f;
    printf("a = " FMT "\n", a,a);
    printf("b = " FMT "\n", b,b);
    printf("c = " FMT "\n", c,c);
    puts("");
    float d=1/3;
    float e=1.0/3.0;
    float f=1.0f/3.0f;
    printf("d = " FMT "\n", d,d);
    printf("e = " FMT "\n", e,e);
    printf("f = " FMT "\n", f,f);
    puts("");
    double g=Third*3.0;
    double h=ThirdFloat*3.0;
    float i=ThirdFloat*3.0f;
    printf("g = " FMT "\n", g,g);
    printf("h = " FMT "\n", h,h);
    printf("i = " FMT "\n", i,i);
}
```

Output

```
a = 0.00000000000000000e+00, 0x0p+0
b = 3.33333333333333315e-01, 0x1.5555555555555p-2
c = 3.33333343267440796e-01, 0x1.555556p-2

d = 0.00000000000000000e+00, 0x0p+0
e = 3.33333343267440796e-01, 0x1.555556p-2
f = 3.33333343267440796e-01, 0x1.555556p-2

g = 1.00000000000000000e+00, 0x1p+0
h = 1.00000002980232239e+00, 0x1.0000008p+0
i = 1.00000000000000000e+00, 0x1p+0
```

> But i have no idea why g has correct value

1. `(1.0/3.0)*3.0` can evaluate as a `double` at compiler or run time and the *rounded* result is exactly 1.0.
2. `(1.0/3.0)*3.0` can evaluate at compiler or run time using wider than `double` math and the rounded result is exactly 1.0.  Research `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

> and why h isn't the same as i.

`(1.0f/3.0f)` can use `float` math to form the `float` quotient that is noticeably different than one-third: 0.333333343267....  a final `*3.0` is not surprisingly different that 1.0.

The outputs are all correct.  We need to see why the expectation was amiss.

---

OP further asks: "Why is `h` (`float * double`) less accurate than `i` (`float * float`)?"

Both start with `0.333333343267... * 3.0`, not `one-third * 3.0`.
`float * double` is *more* accurate. Both form a product, yet `float * float`  is a `float` product *rounded* to the nearest 1 part in 2<sup>24</sup> whereas the more accurate `float * double` product is a `double` and *rounds* to the nearest 1 part in 2<sup>53</sup>.  The `float * float` round to 1.0000000 whereas `float * double` rounds to 1.0000000298...

Comment: Why is h ( float * double ) less accurate than i ( float * float )? Is it because compiler evaluates (1.0f/3.0f) * 3.0f as 1, so the same thing as in g?

Comment: I tried this ```double h=ThirdFloat*3.0;
    float i=Third*3.0f; ``` because I thought that that can lead to the same mistake (h is float * double, i is double * float), but i seems to be correct.

Comment: In other words, where does the value in h come from?

Answer (score 0):

*But i have no idea why g has correct value (i thought that 1.0/3.0 = 1.0lf/3.0lf*

G has exactly the value it should based on:

```
#define Third (1.0/3.0)    
...
double g=Third*3.0;
```

which is  `g=(1.0/3.0)*3.0;`
Which is `1.000000000000000` (when printed with `"%20.15lf"`)

Comment: I thought that computers cannot use exact values like 1.0/3.0, so they approximate it to 0.3333. How is this possible for computer to use exact values?

Comment: There are some values that can be represented in exact terms, but [a better answer for that question is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: I understand how computers see numbers, the question is about precision. I mean is 1.0/3.0 exacly 1/3 and thats why (1.0/3.0)*3.0 = 1.000000 (the stored value is not approximation but rather both nominator and denomianator), or it has very high precision, but isn't excatly the same (like 1.00000000000000000000000000000135235).

Comment: @Pulpit - Are you able to keep up with the comments, in particular Chux, and the link I provided in comment above (2nd).  They are addressing your questions in great detail.  Precision of variable type is the limiting factor in simplest terms.  That is why when looking at `float` (32 bits) a value may be shown to exact, but when viewed with `double`, variations will show up in the fractional part, as you have shown.  6 digits is not enough to exceed the ability of a `float` to show _near_ exact depiction of (`1.0/3.0`)*3.0`.  As per Chux's suggestion, try it with `"%.17e"`

Comment: I see that the same number can be approximated with lower (float) or higher (double) precision. And the conversion from float to double shows off the float's limitations. That's understandable. But why float * double (like in g) gives lower precision that float * float (like in h). It cannot come from float's limitation. Is it refered to conversion process?

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the answer.

```
#define Third (1.0/3.0)
#define ThirdFloat (1.0f/3.0f)


    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n", ThirdFloat*3.0, ThirdFloat*3.0);//float*double
    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n", ThirdFloat*3.0f, ThirdFloat*3.0f);//float*float
    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n", Third*3.0, Third*3.0);//double*double
    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n\n", Third*3.0f, Third*3.0f);//float*float

    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n", Third, Third);
    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n", ThirdFloat, ThirdFloat);
    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n", 3.0, 3.0);
    printf("%20.15f, %20.15lf\n", 3.0f, 3.0f);
```

And output:

```
   1.000000029802322,    1.000000029802322
   1.000000000000000,    1.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000,    1.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000,    1.000000000000000

   0.333333333333333,    0.333333333333333
   0.333333343267441,    0.333333343267441
   3.000000000000000,    3.000000000000000
   3.000000000000000,    3.000000000000000
```

First line is not accurate because of the limitations of float. Constant `ThirdFloat` has really low precision, so when multiplied by `double`, compiler takes this really bad approximation (`0.333333343267441`), converts it into `double` and multiplies by `3.0` given by `double`, and that gives also wrong result (`1.000000029802322`).

But if `ThirdFloat`, which is `float`, is multiplied by `3.0f`, which is `float` as well, compiler can avoid approximation by taking exact value of `1/3` and multiply it by `3`, that's why i got exact result.